# drupal multilevel menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-7

How to create the multilevel vertical menu in drupal,

somthing like thi screen shot[image]

is there any module available for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice Menus module is a nice way of achieving this without having to tamper with the theming directly.
http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus